# Unload event when changing font size in Windows XP

Tags: wpf

Is it possible to stop the Unloaded, OnApplyTemplate and OnTemplateChanged from triggering when we change the default font size in Windows XP?

[image]

It's been causing us some problems and we haven't figured out a good way to handle it. If you know what other events get triggered under this situation, it would help us a lot too.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is no.  Many of the theme-dependent properties are set up in WPF as dynamic resources, meaning that templates get re-applied, etc. so that WPF apps behave well when those theme-based resources are modified.

Maybe you should re-post your question looking for specific solutions for what's breaking when the user changes theme-based properties.